# How can I change my input shape in the architecture for the cnn(transfer learning)?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network, transfer-learning

I have already made a model and trained it, and then saved the model along with its weights. The input shape in that model is [900,300,1] which is [height,width,channel].

I want to use the same model and changed the top base which are the dense layers but unable to change the input shape for the first Conv2D layer. The new input shape is [800,300,1]. Do I need to define the input layer separately so that I can change it?

I have defined the input shape for the first conv2D layer as follows:

```
keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01), kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding = 'same', input_shape=img_shape, name='conv_01'),
```

and i am trying this code

```
model = keras.models.load_model('W:/MASTER_BAGCHI_SCHALDACH/THESIS/code and dataset/models/12_class_cropped_original_300_900.h5')

from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.models import Model

# New input shape
new_input_shape = (800, 300, 1)  # Replace new_height, new_width, and new_channels with your desired values

# Create a new Conv2D layer with the desired input shape
new_conv_01 = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same', input_shape=new_input_shape, name='conv_01')

# Replace the first Conv2D layer in the model's layers list
model.layers[1] = new_conv_01

# Remove the first layer (input layer) from the model
model = Model(inputs=model.layers[1].input, outputs=model.layers[-1].output)

# Print the summary of the modified model
model.summary()

Model: "model_18"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_7 (InputLayer)        [(None, 900, 300, 32)]    0         
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_10 (Ba  (None, 900, 300, 32)      128       
 tchNormalization)                                               
                                                                 
 pool_01 (AveragePooling2D)  (None, 450, 150, 32)      0         
                                                                 
 conv_02 (Conv2D)            (None, 450, 150, 64)      18496     
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_11 (Ba  (None, 450, 150, 64)      256       
 tchNormalization)                                               
                                                                 
 pool_02 (AveragePooling2D)  (None, 225, 75, 64)       0         
                                                                 
 conv_03 (Conv2D)            (None, 225, 75, 128)      73856     
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_12 (Ba  (None, 225, 75, 128)      512       
 tchNormalization)                                               
                                                                 
 pool_03 (AveragePooling2D)  (None, 112, 37, 128)      0         
                                                                 
 flatten_01 (Flatten)        (None, 530432)            0         
                                                                 
 dropout_01 (Dropout)        (None, 530432)            0         
                                                                 
 dense-03 (Dense)            (None, 128)               67895424  
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_13 (Ba  (None, 128)               512       
 tchNormalization)                                               
                                                                 
 dropout_04 (Dropout)        (None, 128)               0         
                                                                 
 dense-01 (Dense)            (None, 64)                8256      
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_14 (Ba  (None, 64)                256       
 tchNormalization)                                               
                                                                 
 dropout_02 (Dropout)        (None, 64)                0         
                                                                 
 fc_layer (Dense)            (None, 12)                780       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 67998476 (259.39 MB)
Trainable params: 67997644 (259.39 MB)
Non-trainable params: 832 (3.25 KB)
_________________________________________________________________
```

Could someone please help? If there is any missing information then please let me know.
Thanks in advance.